# Mockito erases annotations applied to my class

Tags: annotations, mockito, java-annotations

I have an annotation,

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface JobLoggable {
    JobType jobType();
    JobDomain domain();
    JobStatus jobInitialStatus();
}
```

which I apply to my class

```
@JobLoggable
public class Process {
    public void doSomething() {
        Annotation[] annotations = this.getClass().getAnnotations();
        Assert.assert(annotations.length == 1);
    }
}
```

In my test, I spy on it (not mock it, though it shouldn't matter):

```
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Process process = Mockito.spy(Process.class);
        //spy on some internal methods, capture their return values
        process.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Sadly there are no annotations returned by this.getClass().getAnnotations(). When I look at what class the instance is, it is: Process$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3db5579b

It isn't a true Process class. I suppose this is why it fails to retrieve the annotations.

Maybe there is some trick around this. Any ideas? Thanks guys.

I already tried to mock getClass() on the process instance but it is final, so it cannot be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped by this problem until i read [this documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html):

> **38. Meta data and generic type retention (Since 2.1.0)**
>
> Mockito now preserves annotations on mocked methods and types as well
>   as generic meta data. Previously, a mock type did not preserve
>   annotations on types unless they were explicitly inherited and never
>   retained annotations on methods. As a consequence, the following
>   conditions now hold true:

Looks like the solution is simply updating to >2.1.0 of mockito. I was using 1.10.19. If you're using Java 7, you might have to upgrade to Java 8 though.